# rails extra action when clicking on link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I have a rails app with notifications. Notification has `:checked_at` `datetime` attribute. On the notification index page I link every notification to the notifiable object like `<%= link_to posts_path(anchor: "post_#{notification.notifiable_id}") do %>`.

What I wanna achieve is when clicking on this link (that takes to the notifiable object) the `notification.checked_at attribute` would get updated.

I have some different solutions in my mind like an extra AJAX call when clicking on the link OR having an extra route like `notifications#check_notification` the link helper would point to and after checking the attribute it would redirect_to the original `posts#index` page.

I'm not sure which one is the preferred way (maybe a 3rd one) in rails. Could sby tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another parameter to the `route`, something like `update_checked_at`, then on your `index` action inside the controller, you check if it exists and it is `true`.

```
<%= link_to posts_path(
  anchor: "post_#{notification.notifiable_id}", 
  update_checked_at: true) do %>

def index
  if params[:update_checked_at]
    # Do your thing
```

Comment: MurifoX, is this the rails convention? It works just the params in the URL don't look that good.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar The rails convention tells you to create a custom route and do you thing. =]

Comment: MurifoX, but how? Would you do it via a separate AJAX call or a background job or just simply go to that action first and then redirect_to posts_path action?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar The second option is a more viable one. Custom route redirecting to the index page. Easy to do and reliable. Just make sure the route in question is a `POST` one, since you are sending attributes to do some operation on the server.

Comment: MurifoX, sry I'm confused. Second one is the bg job in my example. So you recommend using the redirection (3rd option) without the bg job?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar Oh yeah, sorry, the 3rd one